# One action per switch press with microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, switches

I've been trying to find out a way for quite a while now on how to have a momentary switch only latch for a short time, and then unlatch. I can't seem to wrap my head around what to do. If this helps, I was going to work on a laser tag gun, so when the trigger is pressed, only a short burst happens once, not continually. Thanks in advance, sorry if this has been posted about, I simply can't find any resources about it.

Comment: Switch on, delay, switch off. Easy.

Comment: Look into Interrupts and Timers on your chosen microcontroller platform. The usual way to do this is an interrupt triggered by button press, which sets a flag (or simply turns on the diode), and sets a timer interrupt to unset that flag after a predefined delay. You can do this without interrupts using a polling loop and busy wait delays, but it prevents you from using the MCU for other tasks while that is happening (or responding to input)

Comment: The issue I've had with that in trying to do that in the past, is that the micro controller still reads the input as pressed, and won't turn off. I'm just a little confused

Comment: Of course the input is pressed, if it is actually pressed. You want to detect the transition.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks crasic. That helps a lot. I understand how do use both, I just wasn't sure the approach.

Comment: @crasic You don't need a dedicated interrupt, actually. If you have a timed main loop (that is driven by timer interrupt), you can just count cycles.

Comment: also make sure you look into denouncing.

Comment: Eugene, I think you may not understand completely, so I'll try to be more clear. Lets say the trigger is pressed, only one pulse from the infrared led should be emitted. If I only detect the changes of state, I would get another pulse from letting go of the trigger. I did debounce the switch with hardware, so its not a problem.

Comment: Let me rtell what I understand, and correct me if I am wrong: You want to detect button press, emit the pulse, and not emit another one until the button released and then pressed again. Right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So it is exactly like telling that the pulse emmision is to be triggered by a non-pressed to pressed transition.

Comment: Yes, ok I think I see where you are going with this. I was misunderstanding what you were saying. So by detecting only the change of state from high to low (assuming pull up), i can achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Yes. You can use this event to turn the laser on and start timer for triggering an interrupt to turn it off. If you want I can write some pseudocode as an answer. I would prefer not to, as I am lazy now :)

Comment: If you want to put that as an answer for other people to see, I think that would be beneficial. I think I understand what to do now though, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some simple pseudo code that is not interrupt based and is not debounced.

```
void main( void ) {
    uint8_t last_state = 0;
    uint8_t btn_state = 0;

    for(;;) {

        btn_state = read_button();

        if( btn_state && !last_state ) {
            emit_pulse();
        }

        last_state = btn_state;
    }
}
```